# Может ли конструктор быть виртуальным?

Tags: java

Это вопрос из теста, а я не особо понимаю что значит виртуальный конструктор.

Comment: в java нет такого понятия как `виртуальный конструктор`

Answer (score 6):

Если специалиста по C++ спросить "как сделать виртуальный конструктор в C++", то начинающий начнет что-то придумывать. Опытный, скорее всего, просто скажет: "это невозможно", но часто это скажет даже агрессивно (потому что его уже достали этим вопросом :) ). (дальше всё написано в контексте C++/Java).

Разберемся почему. Виртуальные функции/методы работают тогда, когда статический и динамический типы переменной не совпадают.

Статический тип - это тип, который "виден" в объявлении переменной, а динамический - это фактический тип. Пример. Допустим, `Foo` - наследник `Bar`, и у нас есть такой код на Java:

```
Bar b = new Foo();
```

Bar - статический тип, Foo - динамический.

Невиртуальные функции/методы вызываются согласно статическому типу, а вирутальные - динамическому. Но тут есть загвоздка - в Java все (или почти все?) методы виртуальные. А в C++ функции класса (да, так тут называются методы) по умолчанию не виртуальные.

А как же вызываются виртуальные функции/методы? Для этого почти везде используют так называемую "таблицу виртуальных методов", и каждый объект имеет указатель(ссылку) на экземпляр такой таблицы (нет смысла хранить в каждом объекте копию). И как только возникает необходимость сделать такой вызов - компилятор вставляет в код несколько инструкций, которые ищут подходящую функцию/метод в этой таблице. Это называется поздним связыванием, и обычно оно медленнее, чем раннее связывание (а оно происходит, когда компилятор знает или догадался, какая функция/метод будет вызвана в определенной точке кода, даже если это виртуальная функция/метод).

Это всё была теория, из которой нужно вынести две главные вещи: виртуальную функцию/метод можно вызвать только тогда, когда у нас есть указатель на реальный (созданный) объект и в нем есть таблица с подходящей функцией/методом. Теперь ответ на вопрос становится прост - виртуальный конструктор невозможен, так как на момент его вызова объекта ещё просто не существует - ещё даже не существует указателя.

Но откуда пошло всё это? А пришло это с Delphi. Там есть такая штука как метакласс. И с помощью метакласса можно передать ссылку на класс (да, ссылка на класс, не на объект) в функцию или метод, где код может создать класс, не зная о том, какой реальный класс. А потом появился C++ Builder, куда притащили VCL, и пришлось немного "расширить C++". А дальше понеслось. Поэтому опытные C++ программисты так взбудораживаются, когда слышат "виртуальный конструктор" - это всё Delphi.

Но если бы теоретически "виртуальный конструктор" существовал, то зачем он мог бы быть нужен? Самая простая причина - десериализация. Представим себе функцию/метод, которая на вход получает XML/JSON и каким-то магическим образом догадывается, какой объект был там сериализован, и возвращает объект нужного типа. Более того, в Java это используется... Просто называется по-другому. А называется это [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Comment: Очень полезно! Теперь это нужно осмыслить)